Connect Azure Container App to Web Server on Azure VM and SQL Server on Azure VM
On Azure I have some Web Servers where users can login, some SQL Servers with user data, and am trying to add a very simple app (currently in a Docker image) that can talk to these two types of servers. I have tried creating a Container App in the hopes that the Web Servers can pass on certain requests to the app and that the app (using a connection string to start the connection) can query the SQL Servers and pass the responses back to the Web Servers, all via internal IP addresses, but I am having a terrible time with networking issues.
Some of the topology is:

Web Server (VM) in my-vnet/mySubNet (VNet) with network-interface-1 (Network Interface) and nsg-1 (Network Security Group)
SQL Server (VM) in my-vnet/mySubNet (VNet) with network-interface-2 (Network Interface) and nsg-2 (Network Security Group)
Two attempted apps:

app-1 (Container App) in containerapp-vnet/containerapp-subnet (VNet) with Address space 10.5.0.0/16 (and peering to my-vnet (VNet) (10.0.1.0/24, 10.1.0.0/16)) in custom containerapp-environment (Environment) with custom Workload Profile (<= 4vCPU/8Gi) and Ingress enabled from anywhere

An inbound security rule on nsg-2 is Allow 10.5.0.0/16 to Any on port 1433


app-2 (Container App) without VNet?? in default managedEnvironment-1 (Environment) with Consumption Workload Profile (<= 4vCPU/8Gi) and Ingress enabled from anywhere



Things I've tried:

Creating app-3 (Container App) in my-vnet/mySubNet

Returns error code "ResourceDeploymentFailure" and mentions updateSubnetTemplate


Temporarily adding inbound security rule on nsg-2 of Allow All to Any on port 1433

App reports that it can connect to the SQL Server (VM) using the public IP address (but not the private IP address)


Trying to figure out if I can use any of the Network Diagnostic Tools (as well as Monitoring > Topology) in the Azure Network Watcher
Banging my head on different walls

My apologies for my ignorance of networking and Azure ecosystem, I don't (yet) know what is important to share in order to describe a solvable problem. If this would be much easier if I changed my approach to, e.g., service endpoints, please let me know. All help appreciated, thanks!
